# ms graph beta endpoint, many apis do not support app permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, intune

many endpoints in the MS Graph **beta** API do not support the *application permission type*, meaning they can only be invoked under a user identity. I would like to have a headless service/daemon running that operates under its own app identity, and is able to do stuff with the graph API
For example [remote locking a managed device](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_devicefe_manageddevice_remotelock).

I would like to know, if MS plans to add this feature in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestions.